# Why does my Prolog predicate succeed twice with the same binding?

Tags: prolog

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm still at the early stages of learning Prolog (SWI-Prolog in case it makes a difference), and probably doing something stupid.

I'm trying to write a predicate `weave/3` that will succeed if the third parameter (list) is the same as if you wove the first two together[*]. For example...

```
weave([1], [a], [1,a]).
weave([1,2], [a,b], [1,a,2,b]).
weave([1,2], [a,b,c,d], [1,a,2,b]).
```

My intention is that if one list is longer than the other (as in the third example), the extra elements are ignored.

My current attempt at this is as follows...

```
weave(_, [], []). % bail out if the first list is longer
weave([], _, []). % bail out if the second list is longer
weave([H1|T1], [H2|T2], Res) :-
  weave(T1, T2, Ts),
  append([H1, H2], Ts, Res).
```

This works fine when the second list is longer than the first...

```
weave([1,2], [a,b,c,d,e,f], Res).
Res = [1, a, 2, b].
```

I get the one binding shown, and the execution ends.

If the first list is longer, I still get the correct binding, but need to press the `;` key and get `false` for execution to end...

```
weave([1,2,3,4], [a,b,c], Res).
Res = [1, a, 2, b, 3, c] ;
false.
```

However, if the lists are the same length, then I get the correct binding, but twice, meaning that after the first one is shown, I press the `;` key, and get the same binding. I don't need to press `;` in this case...

```
weave([1,2,3], [a,b,c], Res).                             
Res = [1, a, 2, b, 3, c] ;
Res = [1, a, 2, b, 3, c].
```

Anyone able to explain what's going on here. Thanks

[*] Not sure if such a predicate already exists, but even if it does, my intention is to learn the language, so writing my own versions of built-in predicates is very useful, even if I only ever use the built-in (and presumably more robust and efficient) ones.

Comment: "*Anyone able to explain what's going on here. Thanks*" - query `?- trace, weave([1,2,3], [a,b,c], Res).` to step through what it's doing.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thanks for that. Lost me a bit trying to follow all the output, but I guess it will become clearer with practice.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a nice method:

```
weave([], _, []).
weave([H|T], L, W) :-
    weave_l_(L, T, H, W).

weave_l_([], _T, _H, []).
weave_l_([LH|LT], T, H, [H, LH|W]) :-
    weave(T, LT, W).
```

This is using [first-argument indexing](https://www.reddit.com/r/prolog/comments/qfd4pj/choicepoints_and_empty_lists/) to avoid unwanted choicepoints, i.e. `[]` vs `[Head|Tail]`.

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- weave([1], [a], W).
W = [1, a].

?- weave([1,2], [a,b], W).
W = [1, a, 2, b].

?- weave([1,2], [a,b,c,d], W).
W = [1, a, 2, b].

?- weave([1,2,3], [a,b,c], W). 
W = [1, a, 2, b, 3, c].
```

When at an unwanted choicepoint, press *asterisk* (i.e. Shift+8) for swi-prolog to show an explanation.

Comment: "*When at an unwanted choicepoint, press asterix (i.e. Shift+8) for swi-prolog to show an explanation.*" - Nice!

Comment: @brebs Thanks for the answer. I'm still trying to digest it, as well as understand the concepts in that linked discussion, but I can see that it's a good investment. Just by the way when you press Shft-8 you get an _asterisk_. Asterix refers to [the cartoon character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix)! Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

```
weave(_, [], []). % bail out if the first list is longer
weave([], _, []). % bail out if the second list is longer
```

These aren't bailing out exactly, they are succeeding and leaving choicepoints, and they aren't doing it if the blank position is *longer*, they're doing it *whatever* the blank position is.

Particularly if it's also an empty list then `weave([], [], []).` succeeds for both of those rules, and that's how input lists of the same length end up, giving you the double solution. One quick option is:

```
weave([], [], []).
weave( L, [], []) :- dif(L, []).  % succeed if L is not empty.
weave([],  R, []) :- dif(R, []).  % same for R. Not weaving the remainder.

weave([H1|T1], [H2|T2], Res) :-
  weave(T1, T2, Ts),
  append([H1, H2], Ts, Res).
```

Edit: here's another version which leaves fewer choicepoints:

```
weave([], _, []).
weave([LH|LT], R, [LH|Res]) :-
    weave(R, LT, Res).
```

Comment: Thanks, your first paragraph really made it clear! Your modified code works, however if the 2nd list is longer than the first, then executions ends immediately. However, in all other cases, I need to press `;` and get `false` before execution ends. Why is that, and is it significant. Thanks again.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel "*Why is that*" - it's a choicepoint; the Prolog system cannot tell that the code should finish, it reads the code top down and it looks at `weave/3` (name and number of arguments) and sees that one of them has suceeded but there are still more of them to check. Then it looks at the first argument, as brebs mentions in their answer, and it can tell that `[]` will not match `[H1|T1]` without trying it, so it rules that one out. The others, maybe L will unify, maybe R will unify, it waits for you to ask it to keep searching and try them - then they don't.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel "*is it significant*" - opinions differ; as it is, it doesn't hurt and it doesn't break your code, it's just mildly annoying. A common fix is to do something like `weave( L, [], []) :- dif(L, []), !.` with `!/0` cut to cut the search short. This is an inelegant hack and can mean solutions to the code exist which Prolog will now never find. Or it can be a pragmatic or performance choice. Apart from that, redesigning your code to not leave choicepoints can be a fun puzzle or a huge time sink for little return, like the version I've edited into my answer.

Comment: Replace `dif(L, []).` by `L = [_|_]` twice

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thanks for the extra comments and the updated answer. The comments clarified it a lot, although I'm still struggling with choicepoints. At least I have some understanding of them now, so will hopefully get it with more practice. However your latest version (with fewer choicepoints) doesn't work. If you try it with `weave([1,2],[a],Res).` you'll see it binds `Res` to `[1, a, 2]` which is wrong. Specifically, if the first list is longer than the second, then `Rs` will include one extra element from the first list. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Here's an equivalent encoding of your predicate, with the explicit "OR" (i.e. `;`):

```
my_weave( P ) :-
  P = (_, [], [])     % 1. either this
  ;                   % OR
  P = ([], _, [])     % 2. this
  ;                             % OR
  P = ([H1|T1], [H2|T2], Res),  % 3. this
  my_weave( (T1, T2, Ts) ),
  append([H1, H2], Ts, Res).
```

And we'd call it with one argument which is a triple, as e.g. `my_weave( ([], [], R) ).`.

Clearly, both matches `([], [], R) = (_, [], [])   % 1.` and `([], [], R) = ([], _, [])   % 2.` succeed, so overall the call succeeds twice, each time instantiating `R = []`.

Even after the second success there is still one more option to consider: `([], [], R) = ([H1|T1], [H2|T2], Res)   % 3`. It will surely fail, but there is no requirement in the Prolog language for this to be detected ahead of time (I think), so the call may proceed as

```
?- my_weave( ([], [], R) ).
R = []        % first success, reporting the instantiating
       ;      % then we press `;` to continue
R = []        % second success, reporting the instantiating
       ;      % then we press `;` again to continue
fail.         % no more successes, the attempt fails, and
              % the failure is reported
```

Usually we want to write our code so that the cases in our predicates are mutually exclusive.